# Existe alguma funcionalidade similar ao Assert (afirmações) em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, debug, assert, contratos

Em linguagens como Python existe um mecanismo de asserção (`assert`) que tem como finalidade afirmar se uma expressão é verdadeira e, caso haja falhas, lança uma exceção.

Na maioria dos casos, creio que é melhor usar uma funcionalidade como `assert` do que toda hora fazer um `if` e depois lançar uma exceção.

Exemplo (com assert):

```
 assert(value, 'Value is invalid')
```

Exemplo (sem `assert`)

```
 if not value:
     raise Exception('Value is invalid')
```

Como estou estudando C# agora, gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira, como a demonstrada no exemplo do `assert`, de lançar uma exceção caso uma afirmação falhe.

Existe essa funcionalidade no C# ou pelo menos algo aproximado?

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu corretamente o `assert` do python, os seus dois códigos não tem a mesma funcionalidade, são parecidos, mas tem a diferença do assert só ser executado em debug, se o programa for executado com otimizações o assert não vai ser executado, então ele serve apenas para ajudar no desenvolvimento
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement

Comment: Caro @LeandroGodoyRosa e é por isto que o autor da pergunta formulou a pergunta, pq se você não entendeu bem a cultura do site, muitas vezes formulamos perguntas dos quais já sabemos a resposta, mas para gerar boas respostas para que futuros visitantes que tenham a duvida real aprendam o certo, é isso que o Wallace fez, ele sabia a resposta, formulou a pergunta e deu a oportunidade de outras pessoas responderem para que sirva como uma fonte de aprendizado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existe o [`Assert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.assert?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#overloads) como conhece.

Dependendo do *framework* de testes que usar, pode ter [muitos outros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-the-assert-classes?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

O .NET possui [contratos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) também. Pode ser útil em alguns cenários onde as pessoas usam *assert* por falta de outra coisa melhor.

**O *assert* não é um substituto de exceções**. Contratos podem ser melhores para isso. Como dá para ver na documentação, o *assert* é para diagnóstico, ou até mesmo para documentação. O mecanismo de exceção é algo que faz parte do código normal e sua execução faz parte do que é esperado que o código execute em certas circunstâncias anormais, não é apenas um extra que deve desaparecer e só tem função durante o desenvolvimento.

Inclusive em muitos casos uma asserção deveria ser usada quando usa-se a exceção.

A asserção só é ligada durante a fase de *debug*, e justamente por isso é mais indicado para depurar código problemático. Quando a aplicação é construída em modo *release* simplesmente não tem o código da asserção no binário (código IL) final.

O mecanismo serve para informar e segurar temporariamente a execução do código quando há problemas em algo que esperava que acontecesse. É uma forma de estabelecer um *breakpoint* condicional.

Seria interessante ver a documentação de toda a classe [`Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) que tem outras funcionalidades bem interessantes que ajudam muito todo o processo de depuração.

Também é útil ver a classe [`Trace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) que pode ajudar o entendimento e depuração de código. Esta classe se mantém em modo *release* e é uma forma de obter informações sobre o real funcionamento da aplicação. Em geral seus métodos devem ser bem leves para não impactar a execução geral e na maioria dos casos deve rodar apenas por um tempo, até ter informações suficientes de uso real.

Ainda que o recurso específico seja igual ao Python, o `Assert()` do C# faz parte de um mecanismo muito mais sofisticado que a maioria ignora, principalmente porque ele não costuma aparecer com a mesma frequência em códigos em produção, e como as pessoas tendem a reproduzir receitas, não tem uma referência para copiar.

## Contratos

Um recurso que acho pouco explorado é o [contrato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). Ainda que o C# poderia ter feito um trabalho melhor, ele é ótimo para estabelecer regras de como o código deve funcionar e criar contratos para métodos e tipos que podem ser verificados em tempo de compilação e decidir se é suficiente ou deve fazer algo em tempo de execução, provavelmente lançando uma exceção.

Com esse mecanismo é possível melhorar a performance mantendo a robustez. Lembre-se que C#, ao contrário de Pyhton, PHP, etc., a performance é importante, e a robustez tem importância fundamental, por isso há preferência para que toda verificação já ocorra em tempo de compilação. Os contratos permitem que a opção do tempo de execução seja feita só quando é impossível resolver em tempo de compilação. Códigos com contratos tem bem menos `if`s e bem menos exceções.

Enquanto a asserção serve para depurar, os contratos servem para garantir em código que tudo esteja conforme o esperado. Inclusive existe asserção dentro dos contratos, quando ela é importante.

Com o perdão dos mesmos termos usados em contextos diferentes, contratos de código fazem parte do contrato dos métodos e tipos. Quando usa `Require()` está fazendo uma extensão das informações dos parâmetros.

Particularmente gosto muito de contratos (em geral não preciso mais ter verificações em tempo de execução, algo ainda é muito comum em muitos códigos por aí). Eu não entendo bem porque a maioria das pessoas não o usa. Já vi algumas críticas a ele porque não é perfeito, mas a opção é tão pior. Entendo que a maioria dos programadores não usam por não conhecerem e porque o grosso do código existente, material e cursos existentes não usam, então fica um ciclo vicioso. Mas programadores que vão além da receita de bolo também não usam com a frequência que eu acho que deveria.

Inclusive os contratos ajudam ferramentas criarem automaticamente boa parte dos testes de unidade que precisa no seu código. Não vejo as pessoas aproveitando isso. Curiosamente eu vejo muitos testes feitos manualmente se provando extremamente falhos porque os programadores têm dificuldade de entender o que realmente precisam testar (claro que testes manuais são necessários em vários casos). Ou as pessoas não testam nada ou elas o fazem sem entender bem o que estão fazendo.

Pra mim o `Debug.Assert()` só para algo que eu sei que é temporário, o que é raro, ou ainda em algo exclusivamente interno. Pelo menos era assim. A Microsoft andou retirando as ferramentas que existiam e os contratos passaram ser menos úteis e a asserção ganhou um pouco de peso. Vamos aguardar um proposta para ter contratos na linguagem.

- Classe [`Contract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).
- [Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [Artigo do Jon Skeet](https://www.infoq.com/articles/code-contracts-csharp).
- [Artigo do Patrick Smacchia](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2013/12/18/code-contracts-is-the-next-coding-practice-you-should-learn-and-use/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mais ágil que uma águia +1

Comment: Isto! É importante lembrar que `assert` não existe em release mode. Ele existe apenas para depuração.

Answer (score 11):

A classe [`System.Diagnostics.Debug`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx) tem vários métodos de Assert que você pode usar para isso.

No seu caso, por exemplo:

```
Debug.Assert(value, "Value is invalid")
```

As chamadas a `Debug.Assert` só são compiladas se você estiver compilando com a opção de Debug; se você fizer a compilação na opção de Release, as chamadas se tornam um no-op, o que faz com que elas sejam bem interessantes durante o desenvolvimento, mas sem causar impacto de performance quando você lança o seu produto.

Comment: Ou seja, `Debug.Assert()` não é igual a atirar exceções no código, quando a expressão falha. Contudo, acredito que sua resposta esteja correta em relação a comparação com Python.

Comment: Depende. Se o código for compilado com a opção de Debug, então se a expressão do Debug.Assert falhar, ele vai jogar uma exceção - ou seja, ele é equivalente (não necessariamente igual) a lançar uma exceção do código. Mas se o código for compilado na opção de Release, então o assert não será executado (e nenhuma exceção será criada, independente dos parâmetros passados).

Comment: O ponto que estou tentando mostrar, sem nenhuma crítica a sua resposta (tanto que dei +1), é que Exceções se comportam de uma maneira específica, independente de como o código é compilado. Já o uso de `Debug.Assert()` serve um outro propósito, o de mostrar problemas no código em modo debug, mas de ser totalmente ignorado em compilação de release, diferente do que ocorre com exceções.

Comment: Verdade, Apesar de na prática em algumas ocasiões exceções e asserts possam ter o mesmo efeito, eles não podem (ou pelo menos não devem) ser trocados um pelo outro (a não ser que você saiba exatamente o que está fazendo).