# Uso de assert ao invés de if

Tags: c, c++, assert

Estava lendo um livro sobre estruturas de dados implementadas em C++ e eis que o autor apresenta o seguinte trecho de código:

```
T& operator[](int i) {
    assert(i >= 0 && i < length);
    return a[i];
  }
```

É um código para acessar um elemento em um *array* no índice `i`.

Minha dúvida é:

Por que o autor utilizou `assert` ao invés de `if`? A razão seria por performance? Em que casos seria melhor utilizar `assert` ao invés de `if`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1571360/6809703

Comment: Asserts são usadas para fazer debug de como sua função esta se comportando e para procurar falhas na execução do codigo, um if é um controle para mudar o fluxo do seu programa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A razão até tem a ver com performance sim.

A função [`assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) pode ser ligada ou desligada com uma diretiva de compilação. Então enquanto está testando você deixa ela ligada, assim se ocorrer um erro de programação, ou seja, neste caso alguém usou como argumento na chamada desta função (ou operador, que não deixa de ser uma função) um valor que ele não poderia ser usado.

Depois da aplicação pronta pode-se desligar o uso e ganhar espaço e processamento.

Obviamente que só pode desligar se foi muito bem testado e há certeza que nunca haverá uma chamada com valores errados. Se bem que se isso acontecer o máximo que ocorrerá é a aplicação quebrar, que é o que o `assert()` faria também, afinal ele sempre termina a aplicação imediatamente se a condição for falsa.

Quando a aplicação pode ser *linkada* dinamicamente (DLL por exemplo) e não se tem o controle do que vai chamar sua função geralmente tem que deixar o `assert()`.

O uso do `assert()` é interessante também porque você pode substituí-lo por uma versão mais poderosa ou que faça algo específico que você necessite.

Então quando gerar o execução para produção mesmo, pode substituir o `assert()` por um código que faça algo diferente de quebrar, pode *logar* o erro e mostrar uma mensagem bonitinha para o usuário, quem sabe até começar de novo.

Tem mais detalhes apesar de ser um pouco diferente porque é outra linguagem em [Qual é a finalidade da função "assert()" e quando devemos utilizá-la?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166719/101) e [Existe alguma funcionalidade similar ao Assert (afirmações) em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128991/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).