# Realizar rastreamento e depuração no .NET

Tags: c#, .net, debug

Durante o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação, há momentos em que fico perdido e desejo compreender como meu código está rodando. Por exemplo, em qual iteração de um determinado laço de repetição ele está, qual o valor de determinada variável.

Até então eu fazia isso exibindo janelas de dialogo, que depois tenho que remover do código. Existe formas melhores de fazer isso?

Ouvi falar do namespace `System.Diagnostics`, sobre ***trace*** / ***debug***, rastreamento e depuração e também sobre o método `Debug.WriteLine()`, mas sobre este último, não consegui aprender a usar, pois não encontrei onde ele escreve a informação. Qual a forma de resolver este problema de forma mais eficiente?

Comment: Se você puser um *breakpoint* no seu código (Clique à esquerda do número da linha ou F9 no Visual Studio, vai por na linha que o cursos estiver), e iniciar a aplicação em modo debug (F5 no Visual Studio), seu código vai parar quando atingir a linha do *breakpoint*. Você poderá ver os valores de todas as variáveis que existirem no momento, além das propriedades das classes instanciadas etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em muitos casos usar o mecanismo de *debug*  do Visual Studio é suficiente. Ele é extremamente poderoso e se as pessoas aprenderem usá-lo serão muito mais produtivas, farão códigos melhores e aprenderão coisas coisas só por causa disto.

De fato as classes [`Trace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) e [`Debug`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) podem ser muito úteis para prover informações adicionais e facilitar o entendimento do código e até o uso do *debugger*.

A primeira classe sempre será incluída no código, então se usar quase sempre deverá ser temporário, ou então deve ser usada para *logging* e em algo absolutamente necessário.

A segunda não é incluída em *release mode*, e isso é bem legal, porque não precisa ficar pondo e tirando do código quando precisa. Claro que isto é útil em situações mais permanente de teste, o que pode ser que seja mais interessante outras técnicas como [contratos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128991/101), [testes de unidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/101) e afins.

Conforme a [documentação do `Debug.WriteLine`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads) é possível [configurar onde será escrito](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Debug_Listeners). O padrão é mandar para o  [`Debug.Log()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.log?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Debugger_Log_System_Int32_System_String_System_String_) que poderá ser mostrado na janela de *Debug* do Visual Studio ou outra ferramenta, e a [saída padrão para *debug* do Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que manterá no [sistema de eventos do SO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/event-tracing-portal?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ([Event viewer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc749408(v=ws.11)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

[image: Visual Studio Output]

Comment: Eu fiquei com uma dúvida, se eu colocar a classe Debug dentro de um if, por exemplo, "se a variável X for igual a 12, rodar o Debug.WriteLine" . Na release ele vai remover só a linha do debug e deixará o if?

Comment: Provavelmente só o *debug*, mas se ficar sem nada dentro é possível que tenha alguma otimização que elimine o `if` ou gere pelo menos um *warning*. De qualquer forma este recurso não deve ser usado desta forma.