# Como usar contratos de métodos e por que?

Tags: c#, .net, contratos

Lendo um livro sobre desenvolvimento .NET, vi uma breve descrição sobre *methods contracts* e procurei saber um pouco mais na internet.

> Ela usa uma sintaxe imperativa que é onerosa e possui baixo suporte das ferramentas. Para usar o contrato na biblioteca e na aplicação, é necessário executar um processo de pós compilação. De forma geral, ele é um projeto interessante, mas necessita de um compilador de primeira classe e de sintaxe de suporte para ser útil.

Encontrei algo relacionado com o seguinte código:

```
public int Insert(T item, int index)
    requires index >= 0 && index <= Count
    ensures return >= 0 && return < Count
{ … }
```

Já na internet também vi que tem pouco conteúdo a respeito, e gostaria de saber o que é, e se realmente vale a pena usar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa sintaxe não existe. Há uma proposta para que ela entre no C#, e torço muito para que entre.

Hoje existe uma [biblioteca de contratos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que faz algo semelhante, mas é bastante inferior. O uso de contratos existe desde o .NET 4.0.

A utilização dele junto com ferramentas de análise estática podem ser poderosas, e de fato ajudava bem. Eu não sei bem porque mas as versões mais novos do Visual Studio não conta mais com as ferramentas e o mecanismo passou ter menos utilidade, a não ser que faça uma série de coisas manuais ou por conta própria.

Não quer dizer que ainda não tenha uso, mas ele não é muito diferente de um `if`, no máximo fica mais semântico. De qualquer forma para ser um mecanismo de primeira classe precisa estar na linguagem e o compilador colaborar.

Contratos podem ser mais interessantes que os mecanismo típicos porque eles **podem** ser resolvidos em tempo de compilação e podem até serem eliminados do código se tornando sem custo de tempo de execução. Implementado da maneira correta pode se tornar parte do contrato do tipo e do método, ou seja, quem chamar aquilo deverá respeitar o contrato de forma direta. E em mecanismos sofisticados isso pode ir propagando e até só a entrada do dado ser verificada se está dentro do contrato eliminando todas as outras verificações por o dado já ser válido (é o ideal, não é simples fazer isso funcionar na linguagem).

Eu gosto do seu uso, mas admito que o estado atual dele no .NET não é tão vantajoso assim, mas também não é tão ruim para evitá-lo. No mínimo dá mais semântica e poderá mudar facilmente depois se o mecanismo for melhorado.

Eu ainda estou tentando descobrir porque eles deixaram de ser enfatizados. Mas o código do .NET usa bastante, acho que todos deveriam usar mais. Ajuda dar mais robustez e legibilidade.

Tem [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) sobre o uso em geral.

Respondi algo sobre eles em [Existe alguma funcionalidade similar ao Assert (afirmações) em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128991/101).

Comment: Em teoria então, caso venha a ser implementado algum dia, ajudaria na performance acima de apenas substituir algum `if` dentro do método além da legibilidade?

Comment: Em alguns casos sim. Hoje pode fazer isto com ferramentas externas, ele pode reescrever o código, mas essas ferramentas não evoluíram mais e não estão mais no VS.

Comment: Tudo bem! Obrigado!